# how to display success message from my backend in vue template

Tags: vue.js

how can i display my success message in vue template

this is my json

```
{
    "data": {
        "message": "Email has been sent, 
    },
}
```

this is my template

```
  <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
      <div class="pt-5">
        {{ message }}
        <button class="button is-medium is-primary">send</button>
        <input
          type="text"
          v-model="email"
        >
      </div>
    </form>
```

this is my script tag

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      message: ""
    };
  },

  methods: {
    async handleSubmit() {
      const response = await axios
        .post("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/forgotPassword", {
          email: this.email
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.message = response.data.message;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
      console.log(response);
    },
    clear() {
      this.$refs.form.reset();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

{{message}} doesn't display anything in my template please hw can i go about this

Comment: have you try logging what's inside `response.data.message;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation seems to work as refer the following example.

Try checking at your response by logging the response.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    message: ""
  }),
  methods: {
    async handleSubmit(){
      await axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then((res) => {
        this.message = res.data.id
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.27.2/axios.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
    <button type="submit">Post data</button>
    <p>Message : {{message}}</p>
  </form>
</div>
```